# Why I am getting different output on HackerRank than the output of my IDE?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem named "Jumping on the Clouds" on HackerRank.

I have written a code primarily and it gives the right output as my expectations. But when I am submitting the code on HackerRank it gives different output with the same input. How it is possible!

I tried to compile in different IDE and text editors like CodeBlocks, VSCode, and an online compiler(Ideone) and they give the correct output but HackerRank is showing a different output.

My code (C++):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, count = 0;
  cin >> n;

  int arr[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(arr[i + 2] == 0) {
      count++;
      i = i + 1;
    } else if(arr[i + 1] == 0) {
      count++;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  cout << count << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:
**Output on VSCode:**

[image]

**Output on Ideone:**

[image]

**Output on HackerRank:**

[image]

[image]

Problem link: [Jumping on the Clouds](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem)

Where is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because `arr` is accessed out of bounds. The loop constraint is `i < n`, but you access `arr[i + 2]` and `arr[i + 1]`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Now it is working fine after changing to condition from `i < n` to `i < n - 1`.